# Expected spy isAuth to have been called once. It was called 0 times

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test

// This is my component where isAuth service method called in is Task method

```
export class DefaultComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public defaultService: DefaultService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }


  isTask(id) {
    if (id) {
      this.defaultService.isAuth(id);
    }
  }

}
```

// this is my service code

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DefaultService {
    constructor() { }

    isAuth(id: string) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

// this is my unit test where i want to ensure service method is called or not

```
  it('should call isAuth api when isTask method is called', () => {
    component.isTask(123);
    const defaultService = TestBed.inject(DefaultService);
    spyOn(defaultService, 'isAuth');
    expect(defaultService.isAuth).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

// also try with

```
  it('should call isAuth api when isTask method is called', () => {
    const defaultService = TestBed.inject(DefaultService);
    spyOn(component, 'isTask').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(defaultService, 'isAuth');
    expect(defaultService.isAuth).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine.
I have imported the file with

```
Import { DefaultService } from './defaultService';
```

But actual file name is 'defaultservice.ts' so it should be

```
Import { DefaultService } from './defaultservice';
```

Vscode didn't show any warning and also angular didn't give any error.
May be it didn't check path url with casesensitive way.